# how to access /data/app,/proc on Android for normal App

Tags: android, android-ndk

Do you know how to access /data/app, /proc in the app? 
Without root the Andoird phone.

I finkd Dr. Web can do this. http://download.drweb.com/android/?lng=en
How does it achieve this?

Comment: Who is Dr. Web? i want to meet him personally.

Comment: It's an Android app to scan virus. http://download.drweb.com/android/?lng=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have read access to most of it, but not write access.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -l /proc");
```

will give you the folder contents, for example. What do you want to achieve?

Only system apps have access to `/data/app`, so unless you obtain such key from Google, you're out of luck (at least, for non-rooted phones).

To search for installed apps, your best bet is to use `class PackageManager` :

```
public abstract List<ApplicationInfo> getInstalledApplications (int flags)
```

Check the API [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications%28int%29)

PS: before the question comes, I don't have any clue on how to get (if ever possible) a system app key (at least, I don't know how to sign an apk that can be acceptable for the market with such key).

Comment: But this method cannot access /data/app. We want to make a AV app.

Comment: @user Only system apps have access to /data/app.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my ass. Though I cannot access /data/app, but I can access /data/app/SoftKeyboard.apk. And I can access /system/app.

Comment: @user377808 Brother, I have the same problem! How can you access to /system/app without root? Very need!!!