# how to access /data/app/my.apk on Android for JNI of NDK of normal App

Tags: android, android-ndk

1. I want to read myself apk file size in JNI of NDK,my C code is follow:
2. if (bflag==0){
3. FILE* fp;
4. fp=fopen( "/data/app/ziwu.ziwu.ziwu.apk", "r");
5. fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END );
6. int size=ftell(fp);
7. if (size>183650&&size<193750)
8. {
9. bflag=1;
10. }else{
11. return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, www2);
12. }
13. }
14. this code in emulator2.1 run OK,but in real phone run not OK.
15. how to access /data/app/my.apk  on Android for  JNI of NDK of  normal  App?
16. I am a chinese,my English is not very good.
17. i get my apk file size in NDK,so nobody can decompiler my java code to change my
18. apk file size.
19. Does emulator always have root permission?Otherwise why different from emulator
20. and real phone?

Comment: you can do this using java follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2605838/1075066

Comment: I do not want to use java,I want to use C,use JNI,use NDK.

Comment: because i do not want anyone counter compile my java code,so i use ndk

Comment: counter compile mean decompiler?i am chinese,my english is not very good

Comment: i do not understand the sentence "Though I cannot access /data/app, but I can access /data/app/SoftKeyboard.apk" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742513/how-to-access-data-app-proc-on-android-for-normal-app/9458939#9458939

Comment: _i do not understand the sentence "Though I cannot access /data/app, but I can access /data/app/SoftKeyboard.apk"_. The underlying file system is as Linux. Your app _(or the transient user that runs your app, if you want to use strict terms)_ does not have read permissions for the `/data/app` directory, but the files in this directory can be read by anyone (as long as she knows the exact path).

Answer (score 0):

If your app package is `ziwu.ziwu.ziwu`, then the APK file will most likely be `"/data/app/ziwu.ziwu.ziwu-1.apk"` and any process on the device has read access to this file. Only the **root** and the owner of this file (user **system**) have write permissions.